# Best way to cache images from Parse with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was normally trying to load the image for each cell like so in my UITableView using Parse SDK:

```
PFRelation *relation = [object relationForKey:@"images"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = [relation query];
    [relationQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *obj, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            // Adding Image to ImageView
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"image"])
            {


                PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[obj objectForKey:@"image"];
                [image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
                   if (error)
                    {
                        cell.carPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UIImage *carImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        cell.carPhoto.image = carImage;
                    }
                }];

            }
            else
            {
                cell.carPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

            }

        }
    }];
```

The issues with that, is that it is using way too many queries and the cells have a little lag when scrolling and show the pic above for a brief second before the actual. I attempted to change my code to this to use SDWebImage:

```
PFRelation *relation = [object relationForKey:@"images"];
    PFQuery *relationQuery = [relation query];
    [relationQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *obj, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            // Adding Image to ImageView
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"image"])
            {
                PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[obj objectForKey:@"image"];
                NSString *theUrl = image.url;
                NSLog(@"%@", theUrl);
                [cell.carPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[theUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                               placeholderImage:nil];


            }
            else
            {
                cell.carPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

            }

        }
    }];
```

But now I keep getting: -[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c04ab40. Basically my end goal is to have it so images aren't queried every time the tableView is scrolled, and are cached. Any ideas?

Comment: You're on the right track with SDWebImage. (In fact, your other code has a cell reuse bug in it.) You can configure SDWebImage for disk caching, which sounds great for your use case. It looks like you don't have it configured properly. Do you have the headers imported and SDWebImage added to your app's target?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking I do have #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h> added in my implementation file and SDWebImage.framework is showing up in my Link Binary with Libraries.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/885) - maybe one of those fixes will help you?

Comment: Tried those, no luck. I guess I'll just try the Cocopods option.

Comment: I think the method is called `sd_setImageWithURL:…` now. Not sure if that might be your issue.

Comment: Hey Aaron, once I installed it with CocoPods I realized that as well! Thanks for all the help, I got it working now. It turns out I was doing everything correct as far as the code, I think it had to do with me not properly adding in the 'Other Linker Flags', and possibly using an older version of the framework.